# How do I return a vector from a for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

Suppose I have the following code:

```
f <- function(da) {
      v <- numeric(length(unique(da$cyl)))
      for (i in unique(mtcars$cyl)) { 
        each_cylValue_df <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl==i,]
        medianMPG <- median(each_cylValue_df$mpg)
        v[i] <- medianMPG
      }
      v
    }
    f(mtcars)
```

I am trying to use a function to capture the results of a for loop which iterates three times. My intended output is a vector of the median `mpg` value of the three iterated `cyl` values in the `mtcars` data frame, ideally returning the vector `(19.7, 26, 15.2)`. However, when I run the above code, it returns a vector of the proper length, three, but it returns all zeroes. What is the fix to this issue?

Answer (score 3):

We don't need a loop.  It can be done in a group by operation

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, median)
#   cyl  mpg
#1   4 26.0
#2   6 19.7
#3   8 15.2
```

---

Or a `vector` with `tapply`

```
with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, cyl, median))
```

Comment: Suppose rather than `mpg` as the variable I wanted to find the median of, I wanted to find the median of `nrow()` of each df produced by parsing based on `cyl` values. How would I do that?

Comment: In that case, `median(aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, length)$mpg)`

Comment: That returns a singular value, how would I return a vector of the median nrow() value for all three parsed data frames?

Comment: @ArnavHarkenavvy  I don't understand where you are taking the `median`.  `aggregate(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars, length)`  This returns the number of rows for each 'cyl'.  The number of rows is just a single value.  If you need the same replicated, use `rep`

Comment: @ArnavHarkenavvy  Don't know if you need something like this `library(dplyr);mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% mutate(median = median(n))`

Comment: Sorry to re-open this @akrun, but suppose I needed to nest a for loop inside another for loop because I intend to perform multiple operations within each for loop. How would I do this?